# Platform game rendering method

Tags: java, game, graphics

This copies the level graphics but uses a scale parameter. If the scale is 1, it copies a screen size segment. If it's 2, it copies a half-screen size piece and scales it to the screen size, etc.

How can I optimise this game level code or achieve the same outcome but simpler?

```
 public void render(Graphics g){

    int test = (screenwidth/2)-((screenwidth/2)/scale); 
    int test2 = (screenheight/2)-((screenheight/2)/scale); 

    int scaledstartx=test;
    int scaledstarty=test2;
    int scaledwidth=screenwidth-test;
    int scaledheight=screenheight-test2;
    int locationx=(wherex)+halfpwidth-(screenwidth/2);
    int locationy=(wherey)+halfpheight-(screenheight/2);        

    g.drawImage(DrawnLevel,0,0,screenwidth,screenheight,
    scaledstartx+locationx,scaledstarty+locationy, scaledwidth+locationx,scaledheight+locationy, null );    
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code? Where the screenwidth, screenheight, wherex, wherey, halfpwidth and halfpheight variables are declared? Where else they are used? What is their intended purpose? How they are initialized? What is the DrawnLevel (its name looks like a class, but it is being used as a variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets eliminate the `test` and `test2` variables, which are uneeded (we already have `scaledstartx` and `scaledstarty`). Second keep `screenwidth/2` and `screenheight/2` in variables to avoid recalculating it over and over (the compiler will already do this, but doing manually the code will become clearer). Third, to increase the readability a bit, lets avoid doing calculations in the parameters.

So, this is your code now:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {

    int halfScreenWidth = screenwidth / 2;
    int halfScreenHeight = screenheight / 2;
    int scaledStartX = halfScreenWidth - (halfScreenWidth / scale); 
    int scaledStartY = halfScreenHeight - (halfScreenHeight / scale); 

    int scaledWidth = screenwidth - scaledStartX;
    int scaledHeight = screenheight - scaledStartY;
    int locationX = wherex + halfpwidth - halfScreenWidth;
    int locationY = wherey + halfpheight - halfScreenHeight;

    int spriteStartX = scaledStartX + locationX;
    int spriteStartY = scaledStartY + locationY;
    int spriteEndX = scaledWidth + locationX;
    int spriteEndY = scaledHeight + locationY;
    g.drawImage(DrawnLevel, 0, 0, screenwidth, screenheight, spriteStartX,
            spriteStartY, spriteEndX, spriteEndY, null);
 }
```

We can improve it by observing that the terms in the `spriteblabla` variables are decomposed in terms that have `halfScreenWidth` and `halfScreenHeight` both adding and subtracting. So, we can achieve a simpler expression. To do so, lets replace the variables in the assignment to the `spriteblabla` variables:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {

    int halfScreenWidth = screenwidth / 2;
    int halfScreenHeight = screenheight / 2;

    int spriteStartX = halfScreenWidth - (halfScreenWidth / scale) + wherex + halfpwidth - halfScreenWidth;
    int spriteStartY = halfScreenHeight - (halfScreenHeight / scale) + wherey + halfpheight - halfScreenHeight;
    int spriteEndX = screenwidth - (halfScreenWidth - (halfScreenWidth / scale)) + wherex + halfpwidth - halfScreenWidth;
    int spriteEndY = screenheight - (halfScreenHeight - (halfScreenHeight / scale)) + wherey + halfpheight - halfScreenHeight;

    g.drawImage(DrawnLevel, 0, 0, screenwidth, screenheight, spriteStartX,
            spriteStartY, spriteEndX, spriteEndY, null);
 }
```

Now, lets simplify that, since (`halfScreenWidth - halfScreenWidth`) and (`screenwidth - halfScreenWidth - halfScreenWidth`) are zero:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {

    int halfScreenWidth = screenwidth / 2;
    int halfScreenHeight = screenheight / 2;

    int spriteStartX = -(halfScreenWidth / scale) + wherex + halfpwidth;
    int spriteStartY = -(halfScreenHeight / scale) + wherey + halfpheight;
    int spriteEndX = (halfScreenWidth / scale) + wherex + halfpwidth;
    int spriteEndY = (halfScreenHeight / scale) + wherey + halfpheight;

    g.drawImage(DrawnLevel, 0, 0, screenwidth, screenheight, spriteStartX,
            spriteStartY, spriteEndX, spriteEndY, null);
 }
```

Now, moving some common subexpressions into variables:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {

    int halfScaledWidth = screenwidth / 2 / scale;
    int halfScaledHeight = screenheight / 2 / scale;
    int spriteCenterX = wherex + halfpwidth;
    int spriteCenterY = wherey + halfpheight;

    int spriteStartX = spriteCenterX - halfScaledWidth;
    int spriteStartY = spriteCenterY - halfScaledHeight;
    int spriteEndX = spriteCenterX + halfScaledWidth;
    int spriteEndY = spriteCenterY + halfScaledHeight;

    g.drawImage(DrawnLevel, 0, 0, screenwidth, screenheight, spriteStartX,
            spriteStartY, spriteEndX, spriteEndY, null);
 }
```

Comment: Should `assert scale != 0;` somewhere in the code.

Comment: I am assuming that the given code was correct, so didn't thought about asserting. If that is not the case, we should as well `assert screenwidth > 0;`, `assert screenheight > 0;`, `assert DrawnLevel != null;` and  `assert g != null;`.